# ProxyCap forward traffic to Fiddler

Tags: http, https, proxy, fiddler

I see that ProxyCap supports chains, but I cant get it to work. Can someone please describe step-by-step how to forward http and https traffic from ProxyCap to Fiddler? I think this should be possible

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, but it might get an answer if you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish. Fiddler exposes a HTTP proxy running on 127.0.0.1:8888. (It's not a SOCKS proxy). What app are you hoping to chain, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @EricLaw, so is not all about programming. Your comment is great and you should post it as an answer!